# Can't make Netflix work

Tags: pipelight, netflix-desktop

I have followed all of the installation instructions from 
 [here](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html)  and  [here](http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/), and neither the pipelight silverlight plugin or the netflix desktop works; both tell me to install the microsoft silverlight plugin. What else can I do? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Try netflix over wine if pipelight doesn't work: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_watch_Netflix_(Watch_Instantly)_in_Linux
I'm using it and it works well for me.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox you can install the add-on named User agent override. Which enables you to trick Netflix making it believe you are using Firefox in windows. To install it go to the open menu button on the top right of the browser, click on add-ons search User agent override then click install. You have to restart Firefox afterwards for it to load properly. After all is said and done you can just go to the Netflix website and stream as if you were on windows.